# C++ recursive backtracking

Tags: c++

I am trying to do recursive backtracking to find a path from point 0 to point 8. I have defined the paths but its goes 0 1 2 and them stops. Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector< vector<int> > roads;

void find_path(int Point = 0) {
    cout << Point;
    int rds = roads.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < rds; i++) {
        find_path(roads[Point][i]);
    }
}

main() {

    roads.resize(8);
    //VNESUVANJE PATISTA
    roads[0].push_back(1);
    roads[0].push_back(3);
    roads[1].push_back(2);
    roads[3].push_back(4);
    roads[3].push_back(6);
    roads[4].push_back(5);
    roads[4].push_back(7);
    roads[7].push_back(8);
    find_path();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how does find_path() know when it's finished?

Comment: When its calling find_path(7) there is only one way to go thats is 8. And when is 8 there is no way to go so it should stop automatically. (I think :/)

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes i think now it works properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector< vector<int> > roads;
int path_finded = 0; //Added new variable to know if path is finded.

void find_path(int Point = 0) {
    if(Point == 8) { //Checks if the point where we are is 8 and if it is stops the whole thing and chages path_finded to 1

        path_finded = 1;
        return;
    }
    int rds = roads[Point].size();//changed roads.size to roads[Point].size so it gives the size of the possible roads from the point where we are.
    for(int i = 0; i < rds; i++) {
        find_path(roads[Point][i]);
    }
    return;
}

main() {

    roads.resize(8);
    //VNESUVANJE PATISTA
    roads[0].push_back(1);
    roads[0].push_back(3);
    roads[1].push_back(2);
    roads[3].push_back(4);
    roads[3].push_back(6);
    roads[4].push_back(5);
    roads[4].push_back(7);
    roads[7].push_back(8);
    find_path();
    if(path_finded == 1) cout << "RABOTI"; //prints if it works.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You  should be able to generalize the 8 in `if(Point == 8)`. `if(Point == roads.size())` perhaps.

Comment: Yeah but I am just testing to see if it works because I am trying to solve a bit horded problem with this idea but I don't think I will be able to.